# What's the most "Swift-like"/clean way to set a non-nil value with a sync DispatchQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift5, idioms

I have a synchronous, concurrent DispatchQueue that I'm using to grab a value, so that way it will be available immediately in the control flow.

```swift
let isEmpty: Bool

dispatchQueue.sync {
    isEmpty = self.myProtectedArray.isEmpty
}

print(isEmpty) // error
```

Even though by the print statement `isEmpty` will always be assigned a value (due to being synchronous) the Swift compiler does NOT like this.

How should I modify it to be acceptable to the Swift compiler while not being a gross solution? Starting with `var isEmpty: Bool = true` seems stupid because the "initial value" is unclear.

Comment: If this is a concurrent queue, make sure you use `.[a]sync(flags: .barrier) { ... }` on your write operations, otherwise you won't have any of the synchronization effect you're probably looking for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *synchronous* `DispatchQueue` method

```
func sync<T>(execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

*returns* the result of the work item to the caller, which mean that you can assign that as the initialization value to the boolean constant:

```
let isEmpty = dispatchQueue.sync {
    return self.myProtectedArray.isEmpty
}

print(isEmpty) // Compiler happy!
```

As @Rob said, the `self.` is not needed because the closure is not escaping, and the `return` keyword can be omitted in the case of a single-expression closure:

```
let isEmpty = dispatchQueue.sync {
    myProtectedArray.isEmpty
}
```